# AuthenticationEntryPoint only sometimes called

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a simple `AuthenticationEntryPoint` which should set the WWW-Authenticate header for unauthorized requests.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "FormBased");
        response.sendError(401, authException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I use it in one of the configure methods of `AuthorizationServerConfigurer`

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer authorizationServerSecurityConfigurer) throws Exception {
    authorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
}
```

This commence method is not always called, though. It gets called when there is no Authorize header in the request or when the Authorize header value doesn't start with 'Basic'. However, if the Authorize header starts with 'Basic', the commence method is not called (and the value of the response is `Basic realm="oauth2/client"`). How can I ensure that this method gets called?

Comment: To what URLs you send your requests?

Comment: These requests are a POST to `/oauth/token`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by AliDehghani this occurs because the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` uses a `BasicApplicationEntryPoint` regardless of the `ApplicationEntryPoint` declared in `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`.  In order to get `BasicAuthenticationFilter` to use my `CustomApplicationEntryPoint` I needed to create a new `CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter` and add the `@Autowire` annotation to the constructor:

```
@Component
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    public CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                     AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
        super(authenticationManager, authenticationEntryPoint);
    }
}
```

This is then added to one of the configure methods of `AuthorizationServerConfigurer`

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer authorizationServerSecurityConfigurer) throws Exception {
    authorizationServerSecurityConfigurer
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(customBasicAuthenticationFilter);
}
```

Now the application uses my `CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter` - which is functionally equivalent to the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. However, it now includes the declared `AuthenticationEntryPoint` bean during construction - which is my `CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get an Access Token, you should authenticate your client through *HTTP Basic*:

```
Authorization: Basic Base64(client_id:client_secret)
```

> This commence method is not always called, though. It gets called when
>   there is no Authorize header in the request or when the Authorize
>   header value doesn't start with 'Basic'. However, if the Authorize
>   header starts with 'Basic', the commence method is not called

Spring Security maintains a filter chain internally where each of the filters has a particular responsibility and one of them is [`BasicAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java) which would process Basic Authentications. If you take a peek at its `doFilterInteral` mthod, [you would see](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java#L157):

```
if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Basic ")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}
```

If you do not pass an `Authorization` header or your `Authorization` header does not start with `Basic`, it would skip the current filter for other filters in the security filter chain. Eventually it will throw an instance of `AuthenticationException` which will be caught by `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and `ExceptionTranslationFilter` would call your registered `AuthenticationEntryPoint`.

But when you pass a Basic Authorization header, the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` itself would process the authentication tokens. If the passed credentials were invalid, the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` [would catch the exception itself](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java#L194) and call the `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`, not your `AuthenticationEntryPoint`:

```
catch (AuthenticationException failed) {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

    if (debug) {
        this.logger.debug("Authentication request for failed: " + failed);
    }

    this.rememberMeServices.loginFail(request, response);

    onUnsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);

    if (this.ignoreFailure) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else {
        this.authenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response, failed);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I understand now. How can I set which AuthenticationEntryPoint is used by the BasicAuthenticationFilter?